# AHK (Auto Hot Key) IfWinActive is not working

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to use IfWinActive and keep getting below error.  I copy-pasted the example that is in the AHK documentation but same error.  I searched this site and tried using examples posted but same error.

Command used in script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
#space::MsgBox You pressed Win+Spacebar in Notepad.
```

Error Message:

```
Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.

Text:   #IfWinActive ahk_class Notepad
Line:   1
File:   C:\Users\srk\Documents\AutoHotkey\SRK_AHK.ahk

The script was not reloaded; the old version will remain in effect.
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  I had some other commands to replace text but deleted all that and just kept the above 2 commands but no luck :-(  I am using version 2.0

Comment: For AHK v2 see [#HotIf](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/_HotIf.htm)

Comment: Perfect - #HotIf worked.

And then how do I activate calculator using Win+c?  Below script did not work for me :-(

#HotIf ;if not WinExist("Calculator")
#c::WinActivate

Comment: `#HotIf WinExist("Calculator")` `#c::WinActivate`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252495/discussion-between-maskeerr-and-user3419297).